# Adding timeout in an await function of flutter

Tags: flutter, function, async-await, timeout, future

Hi I would like to detect face using google_mlkit_face_detection package. So, I use the function like this:

```
final List<Face> faces = await faceDetector
            .processImage(inputImage);
```

but, to prevent long response of that function, I add timeout like this:

```
final List<Face> faces = await faceDetector
            .processImage(inputImage)
            .timeout(const Duration(seconds: 5), onTimeout: () {
          print("timeout");
          throw "Timeout";
        });
```

but the problem is, when it has already 5 second, it doesn't throw `Timeout`. Is there a right way to timeout an await function ?

Comment: You can use Future.delayed()

Comment: Hi @MendelG I think Future.delayed doesn't seem correct to get a response after timeout a function

Comment: What you have should work (although throwing a `String` is a bad practice, and you can omit the `onTimeout` callback entirely to throw a `TimeoutException`).  What happens?  Is "timeout" printed?  If you see "timeout" printed but can't catch the thrown exception (or in your case, thrown `String`), then something in the middle caught and swallowed it.

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

`Future.wait([faceDetector.processImage(inputImage)]).timeout(timeLimit);`

Comment: `Future.wait` essentially combines multiple `Future`s into a single one, so giving it a `List` with only a single `Future` is pointless and shouldn't make any difference.